# Error shown upon Signing in into wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, web, cpanel

I have a wordpress blog at www.odootechincal.com.

Upon visiting this url the blog will open successfully.

Now, when I open the url www.odootechincal.com/wp-admin , It takes me to the login page.

I enter my credentials and as soon as I click the on 'Log-in', it gives me the following error,

#

Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server closed the connection without sending any data.

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems.

Due to heavy load on the server, connections may be temporarily blocked from locations that fetch an unusually high number of pages.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

#

This is happening since several days. Please help me out with this problem. I am unable to access my Wordpress Admin panel.

Thank you.

Comment: have you checked with your host? error logs?

Comment: I am getting the following error in debug.log file. PHP Notice:  WP_Query was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 3.1! "caller_get_posts" is deprecated. Use "ignore_sticky_posts" instead. in /home/something/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3570

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be the victim of a [Brute Force Attack](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks).  I would recommend contacting your hosting provider and asking if they can look into your error logs for you, and help figure out the source of why you're being locked out.

9/10 times, you'll need to beef up your WordPress installation's security.  [WordPress has an extensive article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) on how to achieve this, I'd highly recommend you to read it over and apply it.